# Group list items into pages, rows and columns

Tags: c#, html, layout

I have a list of labels for printing. Now I have go over the list and print the labels. The layout is specified by how many labels per page and per row on a page I can print.

```
@{
    var labels = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 };
    var labelsPerPage = 10;
    var labelsPerRow = 2;
    var labelCount = labels.Count;
}

@for (var i = 0; i < labelCount; i++) {
    if (i % labelsPerPage == 0) {
        @Html.Raw("<table class=\"page\">")
    }

    if (i % labelsPerRow == 0) {
        @Html.Raw("<tr>")
    }

    <td class="label">@PrintLabel(labels[i])</td>

    if (i % labelsPerRow == (labelsPerRow - 1)) {
        @Html.Raw("</tr>")
    }

    if (i % labelsPerPage == (labelsPerPage - 1)) {
        @Html.Raw("</table>")
    }
}

@helper PrintLabel(int label) {
    @label
}
```

Is there a better method (eg. using LINQ or nested `for`/`foreach` loops) for going through the list and doing something at the start and end of each page and each row?

I would prefer a nested structure to a flat one so it can be used inside a Razor template. The flat version fails here because Razor requires HTML tags to be closed at the end of a code block.

I'm not looking for performance here, I'd rather have more readable code and possibly getting rid of any `Html.Raw()` calls.

Comment: I think you should add more context to it, especially how this is used. Should the results remain flat or do you create some tree later, etc? You'd get better feedback if you added more information.

Comment: I like your fore loop the best, it's the cleanest code and you can control your page brakes based the way you are doing it now. Sure you can page in Linq but why, your code is faster, cleaner, will not new-up anonymous classes. I like the for loop, I'd even use it if I'd have to format it in html as your foreach can't make guesses of current index and ho many are left to come nor the size of the slip, or width of slip. You see the for loop a lot when having to make ATM or cash receipts

Comment: The disadvantage of the `for`-loop is that I have to use `@Html.Raw("<table>")` for printing HTML start or end tags because it is not clear for the linter or Razor compiler that the opened tag will eventually be closed later. This gets really bad if I add some CSS classes to the tags, escape the attribute quotes etc.

Comment: I don't think it will re-open after that edit. Could you include an example of how you would use this? Is this current trivial example an actual use case? Also, it would be better to visualise the layout if you include the Console output.

Comment: _because it triggered marking this question as off-topic_ - this question was off-topic way before that edit. I asked you to add more context but you just ignored that request. In that case, and seeing your comment about rendering html, I think that this code has nothing at all to with your real one.

Comment: I would say this should enough to reopen it. Thanks for posting the real code (I hope). It now makes sense ;-]

Comment: Just for my understanding (if I get the idea to ask another question here at CR): Is it actually relevant for understanding the question that I output HTML tags (instead of printing eg. ZPL printing language commands) even if the code structure is the same? Yes this is _real code_ already in production (except that the label contains more than just a number). What context was missing? The HTML? That it is actually used in a Razor template? I thought a C# code snippet would be easier to run than some Razor template code.

Comment: If you want to get most out of Code Review and the best input then it's in your interest to post the code that is as real as possible. One can do plenty of mistakes or not know many great APIs that you would never hear about if you _hide_ the fact that you are working with html or razor pages. The more you tell us the better feedback you get. There is no such thing as irrelevant code here on Code Review.

Comment: I am much more interested which other ways there are to go through a list and split it in three dimensions or if there is no better way to do it. Next time I have the same problem in C# business logic and output XML or ZPL commands or whatever, but the problem stays the same for me. One flat `for` loop and a stack of `if`s, some nested loops or any functional programming structure. I can't be the first one to layout items coming from one list into columns, rows and pages, am I?

Comment: Nope, your problem is not not splitting a list into thee dimensions but to render a table. What you are describing is a typical xy problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem you think the solution is a more efficient way to split a list but what you really want is a table and that splitting is only what you can think of right now so you believe you need to improve that.

Comment: Btw. I'm not looking for perfomance here. The goal is to have readable code and possibly getting rid of any `Html.Raw()` calls.

Comment: I find your labels a bit trivial, but at least, after your last set of edits, it's clear now what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @dfhwze How does the content of the labels influence how the building of the table should be done? Do you prefer another algorithm if the labels are objects with properties in the list fetched by Entity Framework, fechted one by one from a REST service or actually just numbers printend on an A4 sticker sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing tags only when a row or table is full. Is data always going to fit the table size?

> ```
> if (i % labelsPerRow == (labelsPerRow - 1)) {
>     @Html.Raw("</tr>")
> }
>
> if (i % labelsPerPage == (labelsPerPage - 1)) {
>     @Html.Raw("</table>")
> }
> ```

You could make a functional helper and use that instead. Notice that after the loop, the row and table are ensured to be closed. The purpose is to allow the consumer to pick how to build a `TAggregate` from `TSource` items and observer methods. We're observing every item, table start/end and row start/end.

```
public static class GridRenderer
{
    public static TAggregate Render<TSource, TAggregate>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, TAggregate seed, int pageSize, int rowSize,
        Func<TSource, TAggregate, TAggregate> itemObserver,
        Func<TAggregate, TAggregate> beginPageObserver,
        Func<TAggregate, TAggregate> endPageObserver,
        Func<TAggregate, TAggregate> beginRowObserver,
        Func<TAggregate, TAggregate> endRowObserver)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        if (pageSize <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(pageSize));
        if (rowSize > pageSize) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(rowSize));
        // .. check observers for null

        var items = source.ToList();
        var result = seed;

        if (!items.Any()) return result;

        for (var i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i % pageSize == 0)
            {
                result = beginPageObserver(result);
            }

            if (i % rowSize == 0)
            {
                result = beginRowObserver(result);
            }

            result = itemObserver(items[i], result);

            if ((i + 1) % rowSize == 0)
            {
                result = endRowObserver(result);
            }

            if ((i + 1) % pageSize == 0)
            {
                result = endPageObserver(result);
            }
        }

        if (items.Count % rowSize != 0)
        {
            result = endRowObserver(result);
        }

        if (items.Count % pageSize != 0)
        {
            result = endPageObserver(result);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Let's say your data does not fit the table size and row size.

```
var renderer = new StringBuilder();
GridRenderer.Render(new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, renderer, 4, 2,
    (item, cur) => cur.AppendLine($"    <td class=\"label\">{item}</td>"),
    cur => cur.AppendLine("<table class=\"page\">"),
    cur => cur.AppendLine("</table>"),
    cur => cur.AppendLine("  <tr>"),
    cur => cur.AppendLine("  </tr>"));
var layout = renderer.ToString();
```

The grid still gets created correctly.

```
<table class="page">
  <tr>
    <td class="label">1</td>
    <td class="label">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">3</td>
    <td class="label">4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="page">
  <tr>
    <td class="label">5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note I've used a `StringBuilder`, but you could also use any other class to render the output. You could also change the flow a bit if you want an empty table when no data is available.

Comment: Your solution is great (generic, flexible) and thanks for pointing out unclosed rows/tables. I'd really like a nested version if possible so I can leverage Razor, but if there is none or nobody comes up with one I'll mark this one as an answer.